# Given the Pair Correlation Functions for a Multi-component Fluid, is There a Simple Way to Obtain the Helmholtz Free Energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, partition-function

I think it may not be possible.

Given all the pair correlation functions (e.g. calculated from Ornstein Zernike theory), it seems possible to obtain the internal energy (assuming different species interact through pair-potentials (i.e. potentials that do not involve more than two bodies)).

To obtain the free energy, the "naive" way is to obtain the partition function and take logarithm. Yet it seems not easy (except possibly through cluster expansions? which is not exact.)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I *suspect* the two-particle PMF would be $w_i(r)=-kT\log\Pi_j g_{ij}(r)$ where $i$ and $j$ denote species, then you could integrate this (in spherical coordinates) over all atoms to get the total free energy. Otherwise there are alternative methods. For example, free energy perturbation or thermodynamic integration to get the free energy for a single component of the system, then multiply it up.

Comment: Thanks. For a single-component fluid, I find that the pressure $p$ can be calculated from the radial distribution function. (See the section "thermodynamic properties" of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function).

Comment: Knowing $p$, we can get the grand potential, as $\Omega = - p V$. (See the section "landau free energy" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_potential). But what we want is the Helmholtz free energy; it seems that we need $\mu$, as $\Omega + \mu N = A$. The other route is to obtain $S$; this can be done by differentiating $\Omega$ partially with respect to $T$. Since the internal energy $U$ can be obtained easily from the radial function, we simply calculate $A = U - T S$.